# How to pass more than one input

Tags: powershell

I'm trying to write a PowerShell script which will take particular extension files from different servers. To pass many extensions I know we can use @ followed by extension. When I pick them from an input file and pass it on the script, it doesn't work.

```psh
$ServerName=Get-content "D:\HOMEWARE\BLRMorningCheck\Jerry\servername.txt"

foreach ($server in $ServerName)
{
  $server_host=echo $server | %{$data = $_.split(";"); Write-Output      "$($data[0])"}
  $Targetfolder=echo $server | %{$data = $_.split(";"); Write-Output "$($data[1])"}
  $Ext=echo $server | %{$data = $_.split(";"); Write-Output "$($data[2])"}

  $Extension =@($Ext)

  $Targetfolder=$Targetfolder.Trim('"')

  $Files = Get-Childitem $TargetFolder -Include $Extension -Recurse 

  echo $Files
}
```

My extensions are `*.log`, `*.log*7z`, `*.txt*7z`, `*.txt*`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`$Ext` contains a string, probably with a comma-separated list of extensions. However, a comma-separated string doesn't turn into an array (which is what the `-Include` parameter expects) just because you put it in `@()`. You need to split the string at the delimiter character:

```
PS C:\> $Ext = ".log,.log*7z,*.txt*7z,.txt"
PS C:\> $Ext
.log,.log*7z,*.txt*7z,.txt
PS C:\> $Extension = $Ext -split ','
PS C:\> $Extension
.log
.log*7z
*.txt*7z
.txt
```

Also, like I said in my answer to your previous question, you're probably better off using `Import-Csv` for reading your input file:

```psh
$filename  = 'D:\HOMEWARE\BLRMorningCheck\Jerry\servername.txt'

Import-Csv $filename -Delimiter ';' -Header 'ComputerName', 'TargetFolder', 'Ext' |
  select TargetFolder, @{n='Extensions';e={$_.Ext -split ','}} |
  % { Get-Childitem $_.TargetFolder -Include $_.Extensions -Recurse }
```

Comment: Thanks for the information. I was able to resolve that.

I'm actually importing data from a text file. So Import-Csv is only for CSV files or even it works with text file?

Comment: CSV files are text files, just with a different extension.

Answer (score 1):

@Ansgar has a the correct approach but in case you're new to powershell the more basic syntax below might be easier to understand. If you already know what file extensions you're looking for you don't need to get them from the file, just create an array that contains them.

```powershell
$exts = "*.log",".log*7z","*.txt*7z","*.txt"

$servers = Get-Content "D:\HOMEWARE\BLRMorningCheck\Jerry\servername.txt"

foreach ($server in $servers) {
  $host = $($server.split(';'))[0]
  $targetFolder = $($server.split(';'))[1]
  $files = Get-Childitem $targetFolder -Include $exts -Recurse 

  foreach($f in $files) {
    Write-Output $f.fullname
  }
}
```

Comment: thanks.

I actually cant hardcore the extension value as each server has it's own limitations. Thanks for your faster response.